# Como eliminar líneas que empiezan con espacio y asterisco?

Tags: sed

Como eliminar líneas que empiezan con un espacio y un asterisco ? => "**(  *)**"

Pruebo con:

```
sed -e 's/^*/d o sed -e 's/^ */d'
```

Y no resulta. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Hola Dok Gus, podrías dar un poco de contexto?, eliminar de donde?, que lenguaje?, etc., gracias!.

Comment: Diferencias sutiles según el sistema operativo ¿Cuál es el tuyo?.

Comment: Respondo a Marce y Sal , la repuesta de ferter3006 me resulto ultil.- Perdon por mi ligereza
Sistema Operativo Linux .. Ubuntu Server
Archivo de texto. Son archivo de configurcion en este caso wordpress/wp-config.com .. Pero vale para otros tipos de arhivos de texto que tengan lineas que empiecen con espacio asterico ..

Answer (score 2):

Para **espacio y un asterisco**, no dos espacios, no una cantidad variable de espacios, propongo esta regex:

```
sed '/^ \*/d'
```

Por ejemplo:

```bash
$ echo ' *borrada por UN espacio y asterisco
  *presente por dos espacios
presente
 *tambien borrada' | sed '/^ \*/d'
```

Resultando en:

```
  *presente por dos espacios
presente
```

También podemos usar `grep` y una expresión regular más precisa para complicarnos la vida: `grep -Po '(^ [^\*].*)|(^[^ ].*)'`

En esta expresión regular, pedimos que imprima dos cosas:

1. Una cadena que inicie con un espacio, que su segundo caracter NO SEA un asterisco, y ya luego lo que sea.
2. Una cadena que inicie con lo que sea menos un espacio, y ya luego lo que sea

Si lo probamos así:

```bash
grep -Po '(^ [^\*].*)|(^[^ ].*)' << _test
 *borrada
   *Presente por tres espacios
  *presente por dos espacios
presente
 *tambien borrada
   tambien  presente
_test
```

Nos arroja esto:

```
   *Presente por tres espacios
  *presente por dos espacios
presente
   tambien  presente
```

Una opción más simple es usar un *negative lookahead*: `^(?! \*).*`

Por ejemplo: `grep -Po '^(?! \*).*'`

Puedes probar en la famosísima página de [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mXzO6i/1).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

para borrar las líneas que empieza con un espacio (o más de uno) y seguidamente un asterisco, prueba esto:

```
sed '/^\s*\*/d' archivo.txt
```

Esto eliminará todas las linas que empiezen por cualquier número de espacios seguido de un asterisco.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Funciona

Comment: perfecto pues, acepta entonces la respuesta como válida para que se cierre la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: `\s` son *espacios en blanco*, que incluyen espacios pero también cualquiera de estos: `\n\r\t\f`

Answer (score 0):

Suprime el significado especial que tiene el caracter `*` en una expresión regular dejándolo entre corchetes `[*]`.

```bash
sed -E '/^[[:space:]]+[*]/d' entrada.txt > salida.txt
```

La opción `-E` le indica a **sed** que interprete la expresión regular como [Extendida](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-12), lo cual permite el uso del `+` para indicar que buscamos al menos un *espacio en blanco* antes del *asterisco*. Por defecto, **sed** interpreta expresiones regulares [Básicas](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-1).

Sin la opción `-E`, la solución será más "verbosa":

```bash
sed '/^[[:space:]][[:space:]]*[*]/d' entrada.txt > salida.txt
```

Comment: ¿No se puede escapar con `\`?

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!